# How to use continue keyword in a ternary operator in php

Tags: php

I want to use continue keyword in ternary operator for code simplification. I am trying to following way and found an syntax error.

```
     in_array($SqlPackageCategoryProductResultRowObj->product_id, $individualProduct)?continue:"";
```

How can i use it.

Comment: I'm also pretty sure this code is extremely unreadable with a ternary operator and I would strongly encourage using an if statement.

Comment: It is used in a loop. if in_array() is true then i don't want to execute rest of code in loop

Comment: Does this really simplify the code? Would not a `if` be a lot more suitable and a lot easier to read on a glance, even if it was possible to call `continue` like that?

Comment: Whether or not the code is simplified or not, the question is relevant and interesting even in other contexts -- upvote

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [ternary operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) takes 3 [expressions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.expressions.php) in the form of `(expr1) ? (expr2) : (expr3)`.

`continue` is a [control structure](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.control-structures.php) statement, not an expression. And hence, it can't be an operand of the ternary operator. In fact, none of PHP's operators accept control structures as operands, as far as I'm aware. The same applies to the rest of the broad C-family languages as well.

And for the sake of readability, it is probably better to use an `if` statement in your case.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the ternary operator for this. This is the solution:

```
if (in_array($SqlPackageCategoryProductResultRowObj->product_id, $individualProduct)) 
    continue;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty old but I came across this looking for a similar functionality. I needed to assign a value to a variable if the value existed, and if not, then continue the loop. I achieved this as so:

```
$var = isset($value) ? $value : NULL;

if(is_null($var)) continue;
```

Although this is very likely *not* the best practice, if you wish to use ternary for the first operation, you can set to NULL and then check that to continue.