# How to display a column of data when the parent variable might not be declared?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, conditional-operator, null-coalescing-operator

I am generating some dynamic content in the view layer of my codeigniter project.

```
<td class="<?php echo empty($log->category) ? "noactioncell" :''; ?> text-center align-middle">
<?php echo !empty($log->category) ? foreach($log->category as $c):echo $c->category_name."<br/>"; endforeach; : '';?></td>
```

The trouble is, I am getting the following error in my ternary expression:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected token "foreach"

How can I display the looped `category_name` data separated by `<br/>` tags without generating this error when `$log->category` is not declared?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you have posted is coded wrong way. The right and more readable variant will be like this:

```
<td class="<?php echo empty($log->category) ? "noactioncell" :''; ?> text-center align-middle">
<?php 
    if(!empty($log->category)){
        foreach($log->category as $c){
            echo $c->category_name."<br/>"; 
        }
    }
?>
</td>
```

Here is a good explanation:

> > The ternary operator takes 3 expressions in the form of (expr1) ? (expr2) : (expr3).
>
> continue (**or foreach in your case**) is a control structure statement, not an expression. And
> hence, it can't be an operand of the ternary operator. In fact, none
> of PHP's operators accept control structures as operands, as far as
> I'm aware. The same applies to the rest of the broad C-family
> languages as well.
>
> And for the sake of readability, it is probably better to use an if
> statement in your case.

By @Fabrício Matté [How to use continue keyword in a ternary operator in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23510110/how-to-use-continue-keyword-in-a-ternary-operator-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly glue your columnar data together with `<br>` in a single line of code, but I wouldn't use a ternary expression to do it.

Since your multidimensional object may or may have the `category` property declared, you can use `empty()` for the first condition (ternary expression).  As for the data to be joined as the text of the `<td>`, you can use the null coalescing operator to fall back to an array.  `array_column()` will not complain if you ask for a column that is not declared.  Using this combination of techniques you prevent the unnecessary trailing `</br>` generated in the loop.  Imploding a flat array is a better/cleaner way for this scenario (regardless of your preferred syntax/style).

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/sqBcg))

```
<td class="<?php echo empty($log->category) ? 'noactioncell ' : ''; ?>text-center align-middle">
    <?php echo implode('<br/>', array_column($log->category ?? [], 'category_name')); ?>
</td>
```

Output when `category` has 3 `category_name` properties:

```
<td class="text-center align-middle">
    example1<br/>example2<br/>example3
</td>
```

Output when `category` is not declared:

```
<td class="noactioncell text-center align-middle">
</td>
```

---

Too hard to read?  Okay, spread it out over multiple lines.

```
<td class="<?php echo empty($log->category) ? 'noactioncell ' : ''; ?>text-center align-middle">
    <?php echo implode(
                   '<br/>',
                   array_column(
                       $log->category ?? [],
                       'category_name'
                   )
                ); ?>
</td>
```

Comment: Nice solution, every time i found something new when professional get attention to the questions. Thank you.